# Javascript, sort array alphabetically and nest each alphabet

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am currently working on an ionic2 project. I am getting data in an array, and I have to show it as a contact list style with side alphabet navigation. Please refer the image attached.

The data structure is somewhat like this

```
[
{"id":1,"first_name":"Harcourt"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Cart"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Laina"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Deborah"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Kendricks"}
]
```

I am able to sort array by first_name using lodash. But I could not figure out how to show that sorted array using *ngFor in angular2, so that every time alphabet changes (from A -> B e.g.), the first element can be given a unique id, so that when user tap on side bar alphabet I can scroll to that element.

Please help. Should I create some nested array for this?

[image: sample image]

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you tried to use nested array ? eg: `[ ["Arvin"], ["Boman", "Britannia"], ... ]`

Comment: I don't get it; you're asking for a way to add a unique id, but each object already has a unique `"id"` property. What am I missing here?

Comment: @JeremyThille, its not a  question of unique id for every index of array. I am asking, that in sorted array, whenever, first CHAR of first_name changes, like from a-b or x-y, that index of array elem should have something to identify that a new sublist start from here. And also how can that be displayed using *ngFor in angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```js
let input = [
 { id: 2, first_name: "Cart" },
 { id: 4, first_name: "Deborah" },
 { id: 6, first_name: "Dobby" },
 { id: 1, first_name: "Harcourt" },
 { id: 5, first_name: "Kendricks" },
 { id: 6, first_name: "Lenny" },
 { id: 3, first_name: "Laina" }
    ],
    people = []

let firstLetter = ""

for(let i in input) {
 let currentLetter = input[i].first_name[0].toUpperCase()
 if(currentLetter!=firstLetter) {
  firstLetter = ""+currentLetter
  people.push({ index : firstLetter})
 }
 people.push(input[i])
}

console.log(people)
```

Then in your template, conditionally display either a name or an index :

```
<li *ngFor="let p of people">
    <div *ngIf="p.first_name; else listIndex">
       {{p.firstName}}
    </div>

    <ng-template #listIndex>
        <div class="list-index">
           {{p.index}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
<li>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

link this:

```
let input = [
    { id: 1, first_name: "Harcourt" },
    { id: 2, first_name: "Cart" },
    { id: 3, first_name: "Laina" },
    { id: 4, first_name: "Deborah" },
    { id: 5, first_name: "Kendricks" },
    { id: 6, first_name: "Dobby" },
    { id: 7, first_name: "Lenny" },
];

input.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.first_name.toUpperCase();
    var nameB = b.first_name.toUpperCase();

    if(nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
    }

    if(nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```